# make error *** target pattern contains no '%'. Stop

Tags: makefile

When I am doing make in Red Hat Linux I am getting below error. Same is working in HP Unix.

> ```
> make -f Makefile release
> /users/src/Excalibur/hertz/make/ProjectRules:115: *** target pattern > contains no '%'.  Stop.
> ```

Makefile is using ProjectRules and I have below code at line 115

```
$(COB_OBJS): $(COBSRCDIR)/$$(@:.o=.cbl)
        $(COB) -xcv $(COBSRCDIR)/$(@:.o=.cbl)
```

At end of ProjectMacros file these fields are defined like below:

```
# we need this in order to have the generic lib and exec rules
LIB     = .foob
EXEC    = .foob
DBSERV  = .foob
COB_EXEC = .foob
COB_OBJS = .foob
COB_LIB_OBJS = .foob
COB_LIB = .foob
SHLIB   = .foob
SHLIB_OBJS = .foob
COB_SERV = .foob
DCESERV = .foob
```

I tried to compile the code individually and they are working. While doing make getting the error. I tried to display the values of the variable

```
$ echo $COB_OBJS
-bash: COB_OBJS: unbound variable
$ echo $COBSRCDIR
/users/src/Excalibur/hertz/src/cob
$ echo $COB
cob -g -a -v -C SOURCEFORMAT=FREE -C noalter -C noanim -C noseg -C notrunc -C nonestcall -C nocheckdiv -C noodoslide -C bound
```

Comment: That error message does not appear to be matched to the rule you've presented.  And the rule does not make sense in light of the variable definitions presented.  Perhaps you're expected to do some kind of configuration before building.  In any case, I don't see how we can answer the question without a [mre] that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: I suspect that the value of the `COB_OBJS` variable is bogus.  Note, you can't show the value of a variable defined in a makefile, by running `echo` in the shell that calls make.  The variable only exists inside `make`, while the `make` program is running.  Add something like `$(info COB_OBJS is '$(COB_OBJS)')` to your makefile just before line 115 and see what it's value is, and then figure out why it's bogus.

Comment: I got it resolved after I I removed one of the $ "$(COB_OBJS): $(COBSRCDIR)/$$(@:.o=.cbl)" to "$(COB_OBJS): $(COBSRCDIR)/$(@:.o=.cbl)"